# Add the ability to go to another HTML page in dynamic table made using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, onclick

I am writing a web page that has a table that also has a button in the table to go to an info page. When clicked the button takes you to the info page. The table is also dynamic as in you can add and delete rows as you want. The button will all go to the same info page since the information on the page will be filled in using websockets hooked into another program. I am able to dynamically add buttons and rows to the table correctly in JavaScript but am having trouble make the dynamically added buttons have the `onclick` attribute to go to the info page. When I click the info button nothing happens. Here is my code to dynamically add the button and have the button when clicked go to the info page

```
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var element5 = document.createElement("button");
        element5.type = "button";
        element5.name = "button[]";
        cell6.appendChild(element5);
        element5.innerHTML = "Info";
        cell6.style.textAlign = "center";
        element5.onclick="onClick=location.href='foo.html'";
```

The last line is where I am trying to set the `onclick` attribute, does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `function`, which will act as the event handler to it

```
element5.onclick = function (){
   location.href='foo.html';
}
```

Comment: would I just add this to the function that dynamically allocated the table, or as a separate function in JavaScript?